# SharePoint BDC to extend User Profiles Skills

Tags: user-profile, bdc

I am having some issues getting this working as I would like.  We are on SharePoint 2010 SP1 Dec 2012CU.

I am able to get it working with a 1:1 mapping, but ultimately want to get multiple "skills" added to the user skills property.

To map the two systems, I am using an application ID that we have also store in AD. I have read that possibly using an integer for 1:many mappings doesn't work, so that could be some of my issue, as I am using that to compare to on the filter.

In the source there is a view that has all of the skills, username, and applicationID, with many rows for most users corresponding to a new skill.

I know there is no permission issues in the setup, as I'm able to get it to work using 1:1, once the filter it removed.

I am using SPD to create the BDC, if there are better alternatives, I am certainly open to them.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want to accomplish and the error you are encountering?

Comment: We want to populate the skills user property with data that is already populated in another system.  That way they are not entering the data twice.  Once there, users can search each other skillsets.

Comment: We are not getting an error per say, but when using a 1:1 mapping, only the first skill is returned.  Here is a sampling of the table:

http://i.imgur.com/pkRuJYL.png

The SageID is what we are currently mapping to, and as you can see, there are multiple rows per user.